# How to correctly normalize a floating point value in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, ieee-754

Maybe I don't understand the IEEE754 standard that much, but given a set of floating point values that are `float` or `double`, for example :

```
56.543f 3238.124124f 121.3f ...
```

you are able to convert them in values ranging from `0` to `1`, so you normalize them, by taking an appropriate common factor while considering what is the maximum value and the minimum value in the set.

Now my point is that in this transformation I need a much higher precision for the set of destination that ranges from `0` to `1` if compared to the level of precision that I need in the first one, especially if the values in the first set are covering a wide range of numerical values ( really big and really small values ).

How the `float` or the `double` ( or the IEEE 754 standard if you want ) type can handle this situation while providing more precision for the second set of values knowing that I will basically not need an integer part ?

Or it doesn't handle this at all and I need fixed point math with a totally different type ?

Comment: note that ieee floats are not mandatory in c++

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Is there any compiler that doesn't implement IEEE 754? Or better put, which modern CPU architectures don't implement it?

Comment: @thokra: It usually isn't the compiler, its the hardware. The one I can currently think of is VAX.

Comment: @thokra SSE implementations support FTZ (Flush to zero) and DAZ (Denormals are zero) optimizations, that do not conform to IEEE 754. Depending on your compiler/CRT this is the default.

Comment: Why do you want to map the values to [0, 1]? If you want to do this for some perceived precision improvement, then do not do it, because it will not gain you anything. If you are doing it for another reason, then you should explain that, so that we can understand how it interacts with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil nothing to do with perceptions, it's about the algorithms that I will use on this numbers and the visual representation of them too ( the GUI of my program ), so I basically need normalized numbers.

Comment: @user2485710: “Perceived” in this case does not refer to errors that will be perceived by a viewer of the data but by the perception of the questioner that there is some increase in precision of floating point in the interval [0, 1] compared to some other interval [0, M].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers are stored in a format similar to scientific notation.  Internally, they align the leading `1` of the binary representation to the top of the significand.  Each value is carried with the same number of binary digits of precision relative to its own magnitude.

When you compress your set of floating point values to the range 0..1, the only precision loss you will get will be due to the rounding that occurs in the various steps of the process.

If you're merely compressing by scaling, you will lose only a small amount of precision near the LSBs of the mantissa (around 1 or 2 ulp, where ulp means "units of the last place).

If you also need to shift your data, then things get trickier.  If your data is all positive, then subtracting off the smallest number will not damage anything.  But, if your data is a mixture of positive and negative data, then some of your values near zero may suffer a loss in precision.

If you do all the arithmetic at `double` precision, you'll carry 53 bits of precision through the calculation.  If your precision needs fit within that (which likely they do), then you'll be fine.  Otherwise, the exact numerical performance will depend on the distribution of your data.

Comment: "due to the rounding that occurs" yeah, sure, but I also have bits in the given floating point type that will be unused, so I'm rounding my normalized values while wasting bits, can you see my point ?

Comment: In IEEE 754 64-bit binary, each bit pattern from 0x0 through 0x3ff0_0000_0000_0000 represents a distinct number in [0,1], so you are wasting less than 3 bits out of 64. I would be more worried about rounding.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: That's 10 bits

Answer (score 3):

Single and double IEEE floats have a format where the exponent and fraction parts have fixed bit-width. So this is not possible (i.e. you will always have unused bits if you only store values between 0 and 1). (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Are you sure the 52-bit wide fraction part of a double is not precise enough?

**Edit:** If you use the whole range of the floating format, you will lose precision when normalizing the values. The roundings can be off and enough small values will become 0. Unless you know that this is a problem, don't worry. Otherwise you have to look up some other solution as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: The problem is knowing how big is the maximum value and how small is the smallest value, if there is enough difference in them, the 52 bit portion of a double could be a problem, yes. This is the reason why I would like to not waste any bit in the type, so I can make the most out of this 64 bits.

Comment: Yes this could be a problem if you have such a wide data range and need to not lose any data. Is this the case? You can use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/ to check if you fall below minimum (=0). A floating point division almost always come with a rounding error.

Answer (score 3):

Having binary floating point values (with an implicit leading one) expressed as

```
(1+fraction) * 2^exponent where fraction < 1
```

A division a/b is:

```
a/b = (1+fraction(a)) / (1+fraction(b)) * 2^(exponent(a) - exponent(b))
```

Hence division/multiplication has essentially no loss of precision.

A subtraction a-b is:

```
a-b = (1+fraction(a)) * 2^(exponent(a) - (1+fraction(b)) * exponent(b))
```

Hence a subtraction/addition might have a loss of precision (big - tiny == big) !

Clamping a value x in a range [min, max] to [0, 1]

```
(x - min) / (max - min)
```

will have precision issues if any subtraction has a loss of precision.

Answering your question:
Nothing is, choose a suitable representation (floating point, fraction, multi precision ...) for your algorithms and expected data.

Answer (score 2):

For higher precision you can try http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html.

Note also, that for the numerical critical operations +,- there are special algorithms that minimize the numerical error introduced by the algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

If you have a selection of `double`s and you normalize them to between `0.0` and `1.0`, there are a number of sources of precision loss.  They are all, however, much smaller than you suspect.

First, you will lose some precision in the arithmetic operations required to normalize them as rounding occurs.  This is relatively small -- a bit or so per operation -- and usually relatively random.

Second, the exponent component will no longer be using the positive exponent possibility.

Third, as all the values are positive, the sign bit will also be wasted.

Forth, if the input space does not include +inf or -inf or +NaN or -NaN or the like, those code points will also be wasted.

But, for the most part, you'll waste about 3 bits of information in a 64 bit `double` in your normalization, one of which being the kind of thing that is nearly unavoidable when you deal with finite-bit-width values.

Any 64 bit fixed point representation of the values from 0 to 1 will have far less "range" than `double`s.  A `double` can represent something on the order of `10^-300`, while a 64 bit fixed point representation that includes `1.0` can only go as low as `10^-19` or so.  (The 64 bit fixed point representation can represent `1 - 10^-19` as being distinct from `1`, while the `double` cannot, but the 64 bit fixed point value can not represent anything smaller than `2^-64`, while `double`s can).

Some of the numbers above are approximate, and may depend on rounding/exact format.